# how to share variables between different BASH in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

**Problem :**

In Jenkins, if I want to execute 3 different BASH one after the other (because there is lots of code) but they share variable. What is the best way to have them share those variables? For now I use propfiles between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the [InjectEnv](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) plugin, you can share your variables with your 3 Shell scripts.

You can define the variables with a property file or you can define the variable one by one (MY_VAR1 = value 1, MY_VAR2 = value 2, ...).